# How to set a custom URL path for a controller without creating new routes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I wonder if there is attribute (built-in or some open source) for me to tag my controllers with the specific URL segment I want it to use, as in:

```
[MagicUrlRoute("status")]
public class InternalNameNotToBeRevealed : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Show()
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

This way, instead of "/InternalNameNotToBeRevealed/Show" being what the user sees, it will be "/status/Show". This might be nit-picking, but it bothers that I have to use the controller class name as the official URL path.

Now, I do understand I could create a custom-route on global.asax, but that will be a lot of work for hundreds of controllers.

I found this very handy library to do exactly that, but only for actions:
http://maproutes.codeplex.com/releases/view/39888

I appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a listing of the mappings and just call MapRoute in a loop to register all the custom mappings. The mappings could be a dictionary, or you could even scan all your controllers once on App_Start, collect a custom attribute value and then use those to build the mappings.  However, I'm not sure how well that would perform for a large number of mappings.

If you wanted a higher-performance mechanism, you'd have to create your own Route. You should be able to do this by inheriting from System.Web.Routing.RouteBase and overloading GetRouteData and GetVirtualPath to do the mapping. When constructing RouteData, you can just provide the existing System.Web.Mvc.MvcRouteHandler as the route handler, and as long as your route data contains 'controller' and 'action' values, it should continue down the MVC pipeline. Then just use the Add method on RouteCollection to add your route. You can take a look at MapRoute in System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions for some insight on how MVC adds it's route.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to be the way to go and not too hard to implement.